# Front-end of the website goes to a side when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a front-end using bootstrap. I created it completely. But when I scroll it vertically, it scrolls a bit  horizontally as well and it goes to a side. I want it to be fixed horizontally. I want to scroll it vertically only.

Before it goes to a side

[image: Before it goes to a side]

After it goes to a side

[image]

I tried to figure this out in many ways. But I failed. What should I do to stop this scrolling horizontally?

Comment: Something is breaking your bootstrap grid. Inspect the elements to find out which one.

Comment: You should find out what overflows and fi that instead of fixing the symptom. You likely have a col element without a row element. That's typically what goes wrong in bootstrap themes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide overflow property of 'x' axis of body or your relevant element.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

'overflow-y: auto' is more user friendly than 'scroll'.

Answer (score 1):

use this to hide scrolling in x- direction

```
overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:scroll;
```